# passing server side mvc variables to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking at feedback as to the best and easiest way to pass server side variables from a controller action to the sites html markup and for them to be used then by javascript on the site.

I am working with asp.net mvc4 and trying to find the recommended method of doing such.

Comment: google search gives tons of results...

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi: <sarcasm>Oh, what a useful comment on Stack Overflow!</sarcasm>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

One is attach data-attributes or id's to elements and fetch them using javascript.

Using razor views:

```
<div id="someid" data-name="@item.attribute"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#someid').data('name')
```

Or you can render the data directly into a script tag.

Using razor:

```
 var somevar = "@item"
```

You can also Json.Encode more complex objects.

```
 var somevar = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(object))
```

Comment: Also to emphasize Declan's answer, if you use the `var somevar = "@item";` method you MUST wrap it in the quotes as he has, failing to do so could yield a statement that reads as var `somevar = ;`. This may seem straight forward for strings and such, but is less obvious when dealing with nullable booleans, nullable integers, etc.

Comment: I'd recommend the first approach (in a div- or hidden input-tag) for better separation of content and code. The minute you need to introduce a <script>-tag in a .cshtml file, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Off - For those who use webform : use `var somevar = "<%=item%>";`

Comment: I would say that the best way is data-attr because you don't have any dependencies to have script in your UI code.  function Service() { this.data = $("...").data('info'); }; var service = new Service(); Service.prototype = { doSomething: function() { alert(this.data()); } }