# How to get values from razor to javascript file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to get some data from a SQL database and pass it to a Model class I created.

Before getting the data I want to test the code out with dummy values but I don't know how I can invoke razor in a JavaScript file. I have found examples that explain how to invoke inside of a `<script></script>` block.

This is what the Model class looks like in the cshtml file:

```
var resource = new MvcApplication2.Models.Resources()
    {

        Id = 1000,
        ResourceName= "lala",
        Description = "This is a resource",

        ArtistAuthor="Name of author",

        yearOfResource="yearOfResourece",

        imageUrl= "Image URL",

        date= "Today",

        Keywords = keys,

        Perspective =" Perspective",

    };
```

Then the HTML code follows and the JavaScript files are invoked inside of the body segment of the HTML:

```
<body>
   <script src ="javascriptFile.js" />
 </body>
```

We are trying to keep everything separated and more organized. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822000/passing-server-side-mvc-variables-to-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways I think you can solve the issue.

1. Use ajax request to get the data in your javascriptFile.js and
2. Declare a variable in razor view and assign it before loading your other script.

eg : var javascriptVariable = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(resource));

and access it inside your javascript file.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try with both suggestions.