# How to pass variables from Razor to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, charts

I have one C# variable "value" that I want to pass into JavaScript Chartjs data object. It renders the chart but does not include the two @p values. See code source below:

cshtml file:

```
@{
    int p1 = 43;
    int p2 = 45;


}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>     
    <div style="width: 400px;">
        <canvas id="lineChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript file:

```
var chart = document.getElementById("lineChart");

var data = {
    labels: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My Chart Label",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            data: ['(@p1)', '(@p2)', 50, 48, 47, 52]
        }
    ]
};

var lineChart = new Chart(chart,
    {
        type: 'line',
        data: data
    }
);
```

How can I write it so that it works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Razor within JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing server side mvc variables to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822000/passing-server-side-mvc-variables-to-javascript)

Comment: Sorry, can you edit your answer for two variables @p1 and @p2?

Comment: Add p as a *data* attribute to lineChart element, e,g, *data-p* attrribute and get its value using jQuery : $('#lineChart').data('p')

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var p1 = @p1, p2= @p2;
</script>
```

and use p1, p2.

```
  var data = {
        labels: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My Chart Label",
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0.1,
                data: [p1, p2, 50, 48, 47, 52]
            }
        ]
    };
```

In this case you don't have to use hidden html fields and you can expand your code to use more field like

```
var tempObj ={
                   tempData: "",
                   otherData:"",
                   moreData: ""
             }
```

Comment: One thing to add in is that any "@" that are part of the _static_ javascript code ( as used in JSON+LD for schema.org) would need to be escaped as `{ "@@Key": "Value" }`

Answer (score 8):

Something like below

View:

```
@{
   var p1 = 43;
   var p2 = 45
}


<input type="hidden" id="PassingToJavaScript1" value=@p1>
<input type="hidden" id="PassingToJavaScript2" value=@p2>
```

JavaScript:

```
var p1 = document.getElementById('PassingToJavaScript1').value;
var p2 = document.getElementById('PassingToJavaScript2').value;
```

Comment: Sorry, can you edit your answer for two variables @p1 and @p2?

Answer (score 3):

Use a hidden field which will hold the value and then read the hidden field's value from JavaScript.

Example:

```
@{
    int p = 43;

}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>     
    <div style="width: 400px;">
        <canvas id="lineChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <input type="hidden" id="someId" value="@p" />
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var chart = document.getElementById("lineChart");
var hiddenFieldValue = document.getElementById("someId").value;

var data = {
    labels: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My Chart Label",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            data: ['(hiddenFieldValue)', 45, 50, 48, 47, 52]  // Not really sure how to format the data but you get main idea...
        }
    ]
};

var lineChart = new Chart(chart,
    {
        type: 'line',
        data: data
    }
);
```

Comment: Sorry, can you edit your answer for two variables @p1 and @p2?